# How do I debug broken networking on a clean Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS install on VMware Player?

Tags: networking, 22.04, vmware-player

I've installed VMware Player 17 on a new laptop, and then installed Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS from the ISO image. With this fresh install, I seem to have no network connnectivity.

[image: Ubuntu initial boot screen showing Connection failed Activatrion of network connection failed]

[image: Output from ip a]

[image: netplan config]

[image: nmcli output]

On the Windows side, VMware is configured as bridged:

[image: VMware network configuration]

Internet access is via WiFi:

```
C:\>ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 1:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 3:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::7e67:ce35:8b34:89dd%18
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.220.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 4:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::6eae:8e2d:7b05:986%10
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.189.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Wireless LAN adapter WiFi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : localdomain
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::d7e9:4f6d:f7c6:45ea%4
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.13
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
```

I've tried the obvious:

- Reinstalling VMware.
- Reinstalling a new Ubuntu VM with the same results.
- Fiddling about with config as per various helpful web pages, to no avail.

Clearly something isn't playing ball, but this didn't ought to be broken out of the box. Not being used to netplan, I'm not sure what to try next.

---

Manual `dhclient` doesn't get me anywhere, although it turns out setting a manual IP, subnet, gateway and DNS via the GUI gets me a connection. So what's stopping DHCP working?

[image: dhclient failure]

Comment: Please do not show pictures of text. Always cut and paste the text into the body of the question. This makes it easier to read, can be searched and never cuts off anything. Of course use screen shots if it is not text.

Comment: @David Can't get a network connection -> can't install VMware tools -> can't copy/paste text -> screenshot is the only option short of OCR.

Comment: Cut paste to a file and send with another computer is a way to do that. I do understand the frustration.

Answer (score 1):

How to debug something? Don't change everything all at once. But if you do, be prepared for a day or so checking everything.

Turns out VMware 17.0.1 has a bug in network bridging, see [Workstation Pro/Player latest update 17.0.1 breaks network bridge connectivity](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Pro/Workstation-Pro-Player-latest-update-17-0-1-breaks-network/td-p/2954837). Downgrading to 17.0.0 fixed it! (Although my install file was `VMware-workstation-full-17.0.0-20800274.exe` it must have self-updated soon after as reinstalling that file has fixed it).

What it wasn't:

- OPNsense firewall
- Windows firewall
- WiFi AP
- pihole

Comment: This might be a comment, it certainly is not an answer.